# Episerver-Get all properties of particular datatype in a content area items

Tags: episerver

I have a content area in a page .This content area holds different other blocks as part of content area items.

For instance, News Page has content area. Content area has Carousal block, Hero Block ,XYZ block & so on.

Is there a way to get all the properties of XHTMLstring type from all the blocks(carousal, hero ,xyz).I need to get all the text from these blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If the blocks within the content area all implement a interface that exposes a xhtmlstring, for example IContentWithXhtmlString, then you should be able to access it with something like this.

```
var repo = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
var contentItems = currentPage.MyContentAreaProperty
                         .FilteredItems
                         .Select(x => repo.Get<IContentWithXhtmlString>(x.XhtmlString));
```

Further reading can be found [here](https://www.jondjones.com/learn-episerver-cms/episerver-developers-tutorials/common-web-page-component-tutorials/getting-items-within-an-episerver-content-area-in-code-items-and-filtereditems-explained/)